# Get multidimensional array that reflects category hierarchy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

The title say pretty much everything. How is it possible to get a multidimensional PHP array of WordPress categories that is reflecting the given category hierarchy.

Comment: 1. Get all the categories that have no parent, 2. get their direct children, 3. repeat 2. for each new set of categories. - What have you tried?

Comment: I digged into WP utility functions based around cat handling and fiddled with get_categories. Just now i thought about the exact same thing you suggested :D

Comment: So are you still unsure? If you figured it out yourself, feel free to either delete the question or answer it on your own (and then accept it once possible). If you need more help, please update the question with the specifics you're struggling with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is a function that can be used just like WordPress [get_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) but returns a hierarchical array. For this there is a `child_categories` property added to each `WP_TERM` object:

```
function get_categories_hierarchical( $args = array() ) {

    if( !isset( $args[ 'parent' ] ) ) $args[ 'parent' ] = 0;

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach( $categories as $key => $category ):

        $args[ 'parent' ] = $category->term_id;

        $categories[ $key ]->child_categories = get_categories_hierarchical( $args );

    endforeach;

    return $categories;

}
```

This function can be used for example like this (to build a row of HTML select inputs out of the first two levels of the category hierarchy):

```
<?php if( $categories = get_categories_hierarchical() ): foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>

    <label for="filter_cat_<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></label>

    <select name="filter_cat_<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>" id="filter_cat_<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>">

        <?php if( $category->child_categories ) foreach( $category->child_categories as $subcategory ): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $subcategory->term_id; ?>"<?php if( $_GET[ 'filter_cat_' . $category->term_id ] == $subcategory->term_id ) echo ' selected'; ?>><?php echo $subcategory->name; ?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </select>

<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Also check out [wp_dropdown_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) and [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) wich already may do what you need without the need of an additional function.